# How to specify multiple path patterns for a CloudFront Behavior?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I have a CloudFront distribution with an s3 origin and a custom origin. I would like all traffic on `/api/*` and `/admin/*` to go to the custom origin, and all other traffic to go to the s3 origin. Currently I have it working with only `/api/*`:

```py
                cloudfront.SourceConfiguration(
                    custom_origin_source=cloudfront.CustomOriginConfig(
                        domain_name=alb,
                        origin_protocol_policy=cloudfront.OriginProtocolPolicy.MATCH_VIEWER,
                    ),
                    behaviors=[
                        cloudfront.Behavior(
                            allowed_methods=cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.ALL,
                            path_pattern="/api/*",
                            forwarded_values={
                                "headers": ["*"],
                                "cookies": {"forward": "all"},
                                "query_string": True,
                            },
                        )
                    ],
                ),
```

I could probably repeat the behavior with `/api/*`, but I will eventually have some additional paths to add that will need to be routed to the custom origin (ALB), so I'm wondering if there is a way to do this that is more DRY.

Does `path_pattern` accept `/{api,admin,other}/*` style patterns? Or should I refactor the Behaviors section to reuse `allowed_methods` and `forwarded_values` and then repeat multiple behaviors with a different `path_pattern`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does path_pattern accept `/{api,admin,other}/*` style patterns?

No, this pattern style is not supported based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern).

> should I refactor?

Yes, you can simply save all the `path_pattern` corresponding to this custom origin into a list, say `path_patterns`. Then use a simple handy Python list comprehension,

```
behaviors=[
    cloudfront.Behavior(
        allowed_methods=cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.ALL,
        path_pattern=pp,
        forwarded_values={
            "headers": ["*"],
            "cookies": {"forward": "all"},
            "query_string": True,
        },
    ) for pp in path_patterns
]
```

Comment: Note also that the default limit to the number of cache behaviors (and therefore path patterns) per distribution is 25 but AWS Support can bump this up on request, to a value as high as 250 if needed.